# How to determine the input for neural network that use timedistributed layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to figure out the way to feed the following neural network, after the training proccess:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, N, channels)),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
            keras.layers.Conv1D(18, 5, strides=3, activation="relu")
        ),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
            keras.layers.Conv1D(20, 5, strides=2, activation="relu")
        ),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.MaxPool1D()),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(22, 5, activation="relu")),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.MaxPool1D()),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Conv1D(24, 5, activation="relu")),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Flatten()),
        keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")),
        keras.layers.RNN(rnn_cell, return_sequences=True),
    ]
)
```

Can somebody to help me to understand how is the layer 0 expecting the input?, is a 3D array?, 2D array? Another array type?. During training phase the input shape has the value 541 for 'N' and 1 for 'channels'.
The code for the training is:

```
# Train the model
model.fit(
    x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid)
)


Thanks in advance.
```

I am trying to feed the layer 0 of a neural netowrk